# Should off-topic chat messages be moved to more suitable chat rooms?

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

This seems like a ridiculous question to ask given the existence of the *message admin* feature, but I managed to get sucked into a discussion about this in the chat rooms and would like some clarification.

As room owners, we're given tools to move messages out of the room into a different, more suitable room.  So when I saw a very long discussion on religion in the [JavaScript chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript), I [relocated the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2057120#2057120) to

> [Casual Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat)
> This is the room for casual chat. Long lines of code will be moved to bin or respective rooms. Enjoy your stay!

This was followed by one of the *Casual Chat* room owners joining *JavaScript* and [insisting](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2059106#2059106) that I should not be moving casual chat messages to the *Casual Chat* room.  Instead, apparently I should have moved the messages to one of the (many?) *"bin"* rooms.

I'm not sure I understand this reasoning.  The description for *Casual Chat* indicates that on-topic, programming discussions will be moved to the relevant rooms, yet they don't want off-topic, non-programming related discussions moved to that room?

What's the community's thoughts on this? It was always my understanding that channels should remain on-topic and messages should be moved to more appropriate rooms if not.  *Arguably*, a casual chat room is entirely off-topic for SO, but I don't have a problem with it being there — it serves a purpose by keeping the on-topic rooms clean.

Comment: I've tried that and it just caused confusion.

Comment: It would be nice if I could get some more objective comments on this.  Most of the answers so far are from people who were involved in the dispute. I'm happy to accept that what I did wasn't the correct procedure, but so far I'm just confused as to why we have these tools after reading these answers and the comment replies to them.

Comment: I've been criticized myself for flinging stuff around between chatrooms too much, but I've grown to accept that basically the only use case where it doesn't cause confusion and sorrow is if you split a discussion in its own room. A "casual chat" room is a bad idea: _all chat ought to be casual!_ Actual content goes in the site.

Comment: Could it have been moved to [bin](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/549/bin) rather than the room it was moved to?

Comment: @badp, indeed. All chat *should* be casual however if you take a look at the SO rooms many are filled for requests for help. It's not just SO either, the "room brief" for ServerFaults "general" room is `This is *NOT* a place for 'Live Support', ask questions on the main site.`

Comment: @tombull89 Then you don't need to move casual chat messages to a casual chat room. You need to move the help vampires away.

Comment: @badp, if it were so easy...

Comment: @tombull89 I know it's not. But moving what should be the whole point of chat _away_ from other chatrooms sounds like throwing the child but not the water.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just occurred to me that there's probably a very clear answer here.

**Ask the users to create their own room and migrate the messages there**.

I think as always there's not one single hard and fast rule. If you know the messages are on topic in a specific room, or you know the room owner of a specific room won't mind messages being moved there, then use that room.

I can't understand why a room called "Casual Chat" wouldn't want messages which appear to be, well, "casual" chatting. But then again when I was on chat I spent 99.9% of my time in The MSO Tavern, which was a free-for-all anything goes kind of place.

So, as Frankenstein said in the comments:

> if there is a person in JavaScrip asking some basic Question on Android and the user in your room cant answer..but you know one room "Android" where they can be easily answered..so you can move it to there..and the person who posted the message get invite to "Android" room..

If it's one or two posts that are off-topic, and you know where they're on-topic, move them to the room their on-topic for. But as for your response:

> not really. What if the owners of the messages I moved wanted to continue their discussion.

Then I suggest asking them where they want to continue the discussion. Something like "Guys, this discussion is off-topic for this room. I'm going to migrate it to another room. Please either find a more appropriate room or, better yet, create a new room, and I'll move this discussion there for you"

That way if they choose to move it to "Casual Chat" it's like they decided to start there in the first place. If the owner of Casual Chat thinks the messages are off topic, he should ask the users to get a room and move their business there.

**Real conversations which people are actively participating in should not be deleted or moved to a "trash bin," this is rude to the people having the conversation.** Messages *should* be posted in a room that's on topic, but,  that doesn't mean that off-topic messages intrinsically have no value.

Answer (score 6):

If you ask me, there's nothing wrong in moving messages to the chat room which is more suited for the need.

In this case, Casual Chat does give the impression that anything goes:

> This is the room for casual chat
>
> [Define: casual](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Define:%20casual)
>
> ca·su·al/ˈkaZHo͞oəl/ Adjective: Relaxed and unconcerned.

However, some owners can get pricky above having huge walls of text moved in to their rooms, so perhaps it would be best to ask if it's okay to move the chat to the room.

Although, if you're moving messages often, perhaps that's a sign that some policy should be straightened out in your room.

Comment: I think this is only the second time I've moved a discussion this large.  The last time it was a discussion about sports cars (and nobody complained).

Comment: @AndyE'shead Yeah, I understand the discussions get sidetracked once a while

Answer (score 4):

Why are we moving messages between chatrooms in the first place?

If they don't belong in room-X then tell the person so, delete them or leave them there.

Moving them to a room just because the name sounds like a nice place to dump it is a bad idea

Comment: Room owners cannot delete messages, otherwise I would have been happy to do that.  Why do we have the ability to move discussions if we shouldn't be doing it?

Comment: @AndyE'shead That might be useful when ..there is a person in JavaScrip asking some basic Question on Android and the user in your room cant answer..but you know one room "Android" where they can be easily answered..so you can move it to there..and the person who posted the message get invite to "Android" room...Hope you got me.

Comment: Simply put: unless you're a room owner of both rooms and/or have permission from the owners of the other room: **DON'T MIGRATE CRAP**

Comment: @Frankenstein: not really.  What if the owners of the messages I moved wanted to continue their discussion.  Surely *casual chat* is the correct place for them to continue it?

Comment: @AndyE'shead now you're projecting what you think is 'casual chat' onto a room filled with people who might disagree. Either you ask them if they want it or you ask for a mod to delete the messages. Either way, its better to prevent this stuff from getting into your chatroom in the first place.

Comment: @IvoFlipse: perhaps it would be more appropriate if a moderator had to confirm the moving of chat messages between rooms?

Comment: No, the mods have more than enough work on their hands as it is. You do realize that as soon as you've typed more than 1 page of text all those 'off-topic' posts are out of sight and soon enough everyone has forgotten about them. You simply shouldn't care so much about it

Comment: @IvoFlipse there are already many rooms to move the unwanted messages where there are no users to chat, but Andy E is moving the messages in casual chat room where their are many users who are chatting.

Comment: If you're moving message to a 'bin' room, they should have either been deleted or never posted there in the first place. The whole concept of bin rooms is just a workaround because not every user has the privileges to delete messages. That should be your feature request

Comment: @IvoFlipse: that's the argument I'm trying to make, I shouldn't be moving messages to 'bin' rooms because there shouldn't be any 'bin' rooms. It was made clear when chat was first introduced that deletion would be a privilege reserved for mods only and room admins should move any off topic discussions to more appropriate places.

Answer (score 2):

> insisting that I should not be moving casual chat messages to the Casual Chat room. Instead, apparently I should have moved the messages to one of the (many?) "bin" rooms.

Uhh.

> I'm not sure I understand this reasoning.

Me neither. And the reason is because that is not an honest description of what happened.  Insistence was on the point of "these messages aren't relevant to *any* room" and thus should be moved to the bin.

Andy you are dumping garbage on the neighbors lawn instead of in your trash bin. Dump the neighbors *toys* on the neighbors lawn, because that is relevant to their interests. Dump your trash in the trash bin.

Comment: Lalit, the room owner of casual chat, indicated that this discussion would have been acceptable if it had started there, so how can you say it doesn't belong there?

Comment: @AndyE'shead It belongs means..that It's not the only right place to move there..Or you should move your TRASH over there...What Andy? what's this? why are you not trying to understand ..that when few users are chatting ..suddenly some useless..chat comes to them..then they get Disturbed and dont like it at all..so the Room Owner will obviouslly tell you to Stop that...that's it.

Comment: @Frankenstein: the messages slot into their relevant places in the timeline.  A discussion that took place an hour ago will not interrupt a discussion taking place right now.

Answer (score 1):

Casual Chat Room is a chat room its not a BIN to move the messages in that room. There are lots of other BIN rooms in which you can move your messages. Moving your messages in an chat rooms is not a good opinion rather.

**UPDATE**

Rathers the users who are interested in having casual chats are always welcome in the Casual Chat Room. Though the user is from JavaScript Room as well.:)

Comment: *"Rathers the users who are interested in having casual chats are always welcome in the Casual Chat Room."* Does that mean that the discussion would have been acceptable in casual chat if it had started there? If that's the case, then what's the problem with moving it there?

Comment: The problem in moving messages in different one, if you are discussing something in the casual chat room we also can share it and give opnions, but moving messages is just the way to disturb others.

Comment: Hope you know the difference between "moving the messages" and "chat".

Comment: thank you for confirming my thoughts.  So what you're saying is the messages I moved are actually acceptable for that room, but I shouldn't have moved them there. Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: Ah!!!! those who never want to unserstand are always confused in that topic.

Comment: I really do want to understand, but what you say sounds very contradictory.

Comment: I simply said that you can discuss in casual chat room, but moving messages in that room should not be acceptable.

Comment: @AndyE'shead If people have started chat in one room that's ok..but suddenly some stupid messages comes in between your chat..then..It Obviously Disturbs and That's Not Happening Man!!

Comment: @Frankenstein: so you're saying I should be pissed off if somebody moved JavaScript-related messages to the JavaScript room while I was in the middle of a conversation with somebody in that room.  What you and Lalit are saying contradicts the entire point of having these tools available.

Comment: Yes JavaScript messages should be moved to JavaScript...But Casual Chat room is not for Useless talking..people are discussing issues and trying to get solved ..but just the way to talk is casual...it doesn't mean that casual chat is room for useless talking..Its very useful room for sharing knowledge and discussing issues for Developers ..of Any Field..and Allowing them to talk in any language if they find some developer from the same region..thats why name is CASUAL CHAT

Comment: @Frankenstein: that doesn't seem to be Lalit's take on things, and he's a room owner.  The Casual Chat room description even suggests that long lines of code would be moved to the relevant rooms, indicating that programming problems aren't really relevant there.

Comment: @AndyE'shead those lines are for those who are posting long codes.

Comment: Get Well Soon @AndyE'shead :) Cause now I don't think anyone can make you understand...That you are wrong..cause you are not ready to accept it anyhow.

Comment: @Frankenstein: there's no need to be like that.  I said in my comments that I'm willing to accept that I didn't follow correct procedure, but I would like some more input from people that weren't involved and, therefore, biased.  You're starting to sound very trollish now.

Comment: Dont Mind..I am friendly...And I am just telling you that now I have nothing more to say regarding this to you..

Answer (score 0):

The Room Having Name "Casual Chat" doesn't Mean that it's not professional.

And User chatting overthere regarding their Serious issues gets disturbed by JavaScript room's messages that's why that is not the good idea to move those messages to Casual Chat just because the name is Casual Chat.

If the messages posted by the User in you room doesn't suited to your room, you should control your users being off topic and tell them if they want to talk personally they can start room with specific or if you can't control your users...and anyhow need to move those messages...make one Room "Bin of JavaScript" and move your useless messages there.

Hope you understood Well.

I answered this because you said : "So when I saw a very long discussion on religion in the JavaScript chat room, I relocated the discussion to Casual chat"

But According to me moving **[67](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2058677#2058677)**, **[12](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2058790#2058790)** and **[33](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2059046#2059046)** messages at a time is not "**A VERY LONG DISCUSSION**"

Comment: I would consider 79 (67 + 12) messages a very long discussion, since the chat window only displays 100 messages at a time that means 79% of the immediately viewable dialogue is off-topic.  Would you move a discussion about JavaScript to the JavaScript chat room? If not, why not, when it clearly belongs there?

Comment: If that much of messages are useless in one frame..why don't you tell your users to be relavent to the Room Topic..Dont talk rubish that I need to move...simple

Comment: unfortunately, new users join and leave all the time.  Telling people to stay on topic is one thing, only a moron would expect it to actually happen.

Comment: if its not happening to your side...then you also don't need to move those messages to another room..and if you really just want to move then..make one room for that BIN of JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Make the rooms gallery if you don't want off topic chat in technical chat rooms,or make your own bin chat room to transfer off topic chat.It is bit annoying while moving off topic chat in others chat room.IMHO..

Answer (score 0):

I Believe that Casual Chat Room is for faster discussion , when you are having lots of reply to the question you asked. Its very easy method for get fast reply.